# Clean and natural scripting functionality without parsing

Tags: c#, nlp

I'm experimenting with creating a semi-natural scripting language, mostly for my own learning purposes, and for fun. The catch is that it needs to be in native C#, no parsing or lexical analysis on my part, so whatever I do needs to be able to be done through normal syntactical sugar.

I want it to read somewhat like a sentence would, so that it is easy to read and learn, especially for those that aren't especially fluent with programming, but I also want the full functionality of native code available to the user.

For example, in the perfect world it would look like a natural language (English in this case):

```
When an enemy is within 10 units of player, the enemy attacks the player
```

In C#, allowing a sentence like this to actually do what the scripter intends would almost certainly require that this be a string that is run through a parser and lexical analyzer. My goal isn't that I have something this natural, and I don't want the scripter to be using strings to script. I want the scripter to have full access to C#, and have things like syntax highlighting, intellisense, debugging in IDE, etc. So what I'm trying to get it something that reads easily, but is in native C#. A couple of the major hurdles that I don't see a way to overcome is getting rid of periods `.`, commas `,`, and parentheses for empty methods `()`. For example, something like this is feasible but doesn't read very cleanly:

```
// C#
When(Enemy.Condition(Conditions.isWithinDistance(Enemy, Player, 10))), Event(Attack(Enemy, Player))
```

Using a language like Scala you can actually get much closer, because periods and parentheses can be replaced by a single whitespace in many cases. For example, you could take the above statement and make it look something like this in Scala:

```
// Scala
When(Enemy is WithinDistance(Player, 10)) => Then(Attack From(Enemy, Player))
```

This above code would actually compile assuming you setup your engine to handle it, in fact you might be able to coax further parentheses and commas out of this. Without the syntactical sugar in the above example it would be more like this, in Scala:

```
// Scala (without syntactical sugar)
When(Enemy.is(WithinDistance(Player, 10)) => Then(Attack().From(Enemy, Player))
```

The bottom line is I want to get as close as possible to something like the first scala example using native C#. It may be that there is really nothing I can do, but I'm willing to try any tricks that may be possible to make it read more natural, and get the periods, parentheses, and commas out of there (except when they make sense even in natural language).

I'm not as experienced with C# as other languages, so I might not know about some syntax tricks that are available, like macros in C++. Not that macros would actually be a good solution, they would probably cause more problems then they would solve, and would be a debugging nightmare, but you get where I'm going with this, at least in C++ it would be feasible. Is what I'm wanting even possible in C#?

Here's an example, using LINQ and Lambda expressions you can sometimes get the same amount of work done with fewer lines, less symbols, and code the reads closer to English. For example, here's an example of three collisions that happen between pairs of objects with IDs, we want to gather all collisions with the object that has ID 5, then sort those collisions by the "first" ID in the pair, and then output the pairs. Here is how you would do this without LINQ and/or Lambra expressions:

```
struct CollisionPair : IComparable, IComparer
{
    public int first;
    public int second;

    // Since we're sorting we'll need to write our own Comparer
    int IComparer.Compare( object one, object two )
    {
        CollisionPair pairOne = (CollisionPair)one;
        CollisionPair pairTwo = (CollisionPair)two;

        if (pairOne.first < pairTwo.first)
            return -1;
        else if (pairTwo.first < pairOne.first)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    // ...and our own compable
    int IComparable.CompareTo( object two )
    {
        CollisionPair pairTwo = (CollisionPair)two;

        if (this.first < pairTwo.first)
            return -1;
        else if (pairTwo.first < this.first)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{           
    List<CollisionPair> collisions = new List<CollisionPair>
    {
        new CollisionPair { first = 1, second = 5 },
        new CollisionPair { first = 2, second = 3 },
        new CollisionPair { first = 5, second = 4 }
    };

    // In a script this would be all the code you needed, everything above
    // would be part of the game engine   
    List<CollisionPair> sortedCollisionsWithFive = new List<CollisionPair>();
    foreach (CollisionPair c in collisions)
    {
        if (c.first == 5 || c.second == 5)
        {
            sortedCollisionsWithFive.Add(c);
        }
    }
    sortedCollisionsWithFive.Sort();

    foreach (CollisionPair c in sortedCollisionsWithFive)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Collision between " + c.first +
                          " and " + c.second);
    }
}
```

And now the same example with LINQ and Lambda. Notice in this example we don't have to both with making `CollisionPair` both `IComparable` and `IComparer`, and don't have to implement to the `Compare` and `CompareTo` methods:

```
struct CollisionPair
{
    public int first;
    public int second;
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{           
    List<CollisionPair> collisions = new List<CollisionPair>
    {
        new CollisionPair { first = 1, second = 5 },
        new CollisionPair { first = 2, second = 3 },
        new CollisionPair { first = 5, second = 4 }
    };

    // In a script this would be all the code you needed, everything above
    // would be part of the game engine
    (from c in collisions 
    where ( c.first == 5 || c.second == 5 )
    orderby c.first select c).ForEach(c =>
        Console.WriteLine("Collision between " + c.first +
                          " and " + c.second));
}
```

In the end we're left with a LINQ and Lambda expression that read closer to natural language, and are much less code for both a game engine and for the script. These kinds of changes are really what I'm looking for, but obviously LINQ and Lambda are both limited to specific syntax, not something as generic as I would like in the end.

Comment: Have you looked at Coffeescript at all?  It might give you some ideas for syntax, and you can see how they parse the code into plain JS.  `eat food for food in foods when food isnt 'chocolate'` http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: @Jonathan, I need something that is written in native C#, with no parsing or lexical analysis required on my part. I'll add details to my question that makes that more clear.

Comment: I understood the question, I was just providing some info on an implementation of a similar concept albeit different language.

Comment: Have you at least taken a look at Boo, which gives you more control over the parsing pipeline, and might allow you to make this kind of idea look more natural by replacing parentheses with, say, indentation?

Comment: @JasonTrue: Thanks you Jason, those are exactly the kind of things I'm looking for. I guess this wouldn't fall under native C#, but it's pretty close to what I'm looking for, I'll give this one some more consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use FluentInterface "pattern", implement something like:

```
When(enemy).IsWithin(10.units()).Of(player).Then(enemy).Attacks(player);
```

If you make the functions like When, IsWithin, Of, Then return some interfaces, then you will be able easily add new extension methods to expand your rules language.

For example let's take a look at function Then:

```
public IActiveActor Then(this ICondition condition, Actor actor) {
   /* keep the actor, etc */
}

public void Attacks(this IActiveActor who, Actor whom) {
   /* your business logic */
}
```

In the future it would be easy to implement another function, say RunAway() without changing anything in your code:

```
public void RunAway(this IActiveActor who) {
    /* perform runaway logic */
}
```

so it with this little addition you will be able to write:

```
When(player).IsWithin(10.units()).Of(enemy).Then(player).RunAway();
```

Same for conditions, assuming When returns something like ICheckActor, you can introduce new conditions by simply defining new functions:

```
public ICondition IsStrongerThan(this ICheckActor me, Actor anotherGuy) {
    if (CompareStrength(me, anotherGuy) > 0)
       return TrueActorCondition(me);
    else
       return FalseActorCondition(me);
}
```

so now you can do:

```
When(player)
  .IsWithin(10.units()).Of(enemy)
  .And(player).IsStrongerThan(enemy)
  .Then(player)
  .Attacks(enemy);
```

or

```
When(player)
  .IsWithin(10.units()).Of(enemy)
  .And(enemy).IsStrongerThan(player)
  .Then(player)
  .RunAway();
```

The point is that you can improve your language without experiencing heavy impact on the code you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don't think this is a good direction for a language. Take a look at AppleScript sometime. They went to great pains to mimic natural language, and in trivial examples you can write AppleScript that reads like English. In real usage, it's a nightmare. It's awkward and cumbersome to use. And it's hard to learn, because people have a very hard time with "just write this incredibly limited subset of English with no deviations from the set pattern." It's easier to learn real C# syntax, which is regular and predictable.

Comment: Agreed 100%.  English in particular is a horribly imprecise language, making it extremely difficult to get the specificity that you need to write software. Even in the OP's example, there is a lot of fuzziness (when does the attack occur? when the enemy moves? when the player moves? some other time? And which enemy does the attacking, and which player is attacked? The language would need to understand definite articles.)

Comment: This is mostly for experimentation and fun, I've created scripting languages in the past for companies I've worked with, some of which were made for end users. I want to try this as a learning experience, just to see where I can get with it, not because it may be practical.

Comment: Well, I'd start by looking at AppleScript for a day or two before going any further. At the very least, learn from their foibles.

Comment: I'm more interested in ways to work out syntax with C# to get it to read more natural than I am in having an easy to use scripting language. If I wanted something clean and practical I would probably not go for natural language scripting. Ease of use would be a nice bonus, but its second priority to trying to clean up syntax to make it read more like a natural language than a programming language. A result that read like AppleScript would be fine by me, but the main point of the question is that I don't think I can achieve that using C# syntax.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure you can't go all Scala-y and get rid of the dots and parentheses everywhere. If that's what you're really asking, "can I make a complex expression with little or no punctuation?", I'm thinking it's a solid no.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx . Something like this is what would've been helpful. Notice the code in the sample does things like queries without any periods, or parenthesis, etc. I wasn't aware this was something that could be done in C#.

Comment: I understand, but I can use LINQ within C# 4.0 with the project so that works out great for scripting. Also, stuff like this is useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx, allowing me to override behavior of primitive types within the scope of the scripts.

Comment: Could you show an example of how you plan to combine LINQ and extension methods to call arbitrarily-named methods without using regular C# dot-and-parentheses syntax? I am not seeing your point at all.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Sure, I've added new details to the bottom of my original question comparing code without LINQ or Lambda against code using both. Notice by using LINQ and Lambda it's much less code, and less symbols and syntax for a user to deal with. Not to mention there are hundreds of ways to use LINQ. I may even be able to wrap entire expressions for an end-user to simplify further, of course I could do that without LINQ as well.

Comment: What you posted looks exactly like LINQ code, and nothing at all like your original request. I'm glad it serves your needs but I don't think your question is well-formed at this point.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Maybe you're right, my question gave a specific example, but the question itself was generic in that I wanted ways to write code without as many symbols, something that would read closer to a natural language. LINQ and Lambda expressions don't get me all the way there, they're just an example of the kinds of things I'm looking for. The LINQ example I posted was also off the top of my head, I didn't have something prepared that matched anything close to the original example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your requirement of "written in native C#". Why? Probably you want it to be **written in native .NET**? I can understand this as you can compile these rules written in "plain English" into .NET with no parsing etc. Then your engine (probably written in C#) will be able to use these rules, evaluate them, etc. Just because it is all .NET, doesn't really matter which language developer used.

Now, if C# is not really a requirement, then we can stop figuring out how to make "ugly-ugly" syntax look "just ugly" :)

We can look at, for example, F#. It compiles into .NET in the same way C# or VB.NET do, but it is more suitable for solving problems like yours.

You gave us 3 (ugly looking) examples in C# and Scala, here is one in F# I managed to write from the top of my head in 5 minutes:

```
When enemy (within 10<unit> player) (Then enemy attacks player)
```

I only spent 5 minutes, so probably it can be even prettier.
No parsing is involved, When, within, Then, attacks are just normal .NET functions (written in F#).

Here is all the code I had to write to make it possible:

```
[<Measure>] type unit
type Position = int<unit>

type Actor  =
    | Enemy of Position
    | Player of Position

let getPosition actor =
    match actor with
        | Enemy x -> x
        | Player x -> x

let When actor condition positiveAction =
    if condition actor
    then positiveAction
    else ()

let Then actor action = action actor

let within distance actor1 actor2 =
    let pos1 = getPosition actor1
    let pos2 = getPosition actor2
    abs (pos1 - pos2) <= distance

let attacks victim agressor =
    printfn "%s attacks %s" (agressor.GetType().Name) (victim.GetType().Name)
```

This is really it, not hundreds and hundreds of lines of code you would probably write in C# :)
This is a beauty of .NET: you can use appropriate languages for appropriate tasks. And F# is a good language for DLS (just what you need here)

P.S. You can even define functions like "an", "the", "in", etc to make it look more like English (these functions will do nothing but return their first argument):

```
let an something = something
let the = an
let is = an
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is super impressive, but just for the sake of argument, my impression is that this technique leads to F# functions that are easy to read once written--but does **not** necessarily make them any easier to write. You still need a language reference and computer science precision to write one with perfect syntax; it just reads nicely once you're done. And we still haven't tackled any interesting issues like looping constructs or comparisons/branching.

Comment: C# is a requirement because I'm using XNA.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Agree, F# may not be easy for everyone to write (despite the fact that you write much less and because of that has some time to learn). Then look at my next suggestion: fluent configuration :)